# Best way to copy multiple files to multiple remote servers

Tags: python, automation

I'm developing a service which has to copy multiple files from a central node to remote servers.

The problem is that each time the service is executed, there are new servers and new files to dispatch to these servers. I mean, in each execution, I have the information of which files have to be copied to each server and in which directory.

Obviously, this information is very dynamically changing, so I would like to be able to automatize this task. I tried to get a solution with **Ansible, FTP and SCP over Python**.

- I think Ansible is very difficult to automatize every scp task in each execution.
- SCP is ok but I need to build each SCP command in Python to launch it.
- FTP Is too much for this problem because there are not many files to dispatch to a single server.

Is there any better solution than what I thinked about?

Answer (score 0):

In case you send some the same file (or files) to different destinations (that can be organized as sets), you could profit from solutions as **dsh** or **parallel-scp**.

If this will make sense depends on your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

> [Parallel-SSH Documentation](http://parallel-ssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
from __future__ import print_function

from pssh.pssh_client import ParallelSSHClient

hosts = ['myhost1', 'myhost2']
client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts)

output = client.run_command('uname')
for host, host_output in output.items():
    for line in host_output.stdout:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about rsync ?
Example: rsync -rave

Where source or destination could be:
user@IP:/path/to/dest

It knows incremental + you can Cron it or trigger a small script when anything changes